# Functional vs Object Oriented Approach for UI codes

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, functional-programming

I have the following snippets. which formats error messages based on a map. I can do it as a simple function call the function for transforming the error. or create a class and handle it in that way.

Functional doesn't require a an object instantiation and the message are exposed so that can imported in test to verify

Object Oriented will more structure but should be instantiated every time its accessed.

**Functional**

*error_handler.js*

```
export const messages = {
 500: 'Unexpected Error Occurred'
 400: 'Bad Request'
}

function transformError(error) {
 const message = messages[error.statusCode]
 return new Error(message)
}
```

*error_handler.spec.js*

```
it('should work for 400',() => {
  const error  = transformError({ statusCode :400 })
  expect(error.message).toEqual(messages[400]);
})
```

```
call().catch(transformError)
```

**Object Oriented**

````
class FormattedError {
 constructor(error){
   const messages = {
     500: 'Unexpected Error Occurred'
     400: 'Bad Request'
   }

   return new Error(messages[error.statusCode]);
 }
}

```

```
call().catch(e => new FormattedError(e))
```

```
it('should work for 400',() => {
  const error  = transformError({ statusCode :400 })
  expect(error.message).not.toBe(null)
})
```


What should be the ideal approach consider this is for UI
````

Comment: A class is generally used to keep track of a state. If you don't need that you might as well use functions. If your whole app is built in an OOP way, you can use static functions in a helper class, such as for example `Math.round()`. Either way, the code that you wrote seems unwieldy, so it's hard to see what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Object oriented doesn't really makes sense to me here. That `FormattedError` class doesn't even represent anything, just transforming error constructor parameter to another class.

Also you are calling constructor, that then returns instance of something else? I don't know javascript that much so maybe it's some unknown construct to me, but that looks like something terribly wrong.

Edit:

I see no relevance to code being UI code or not.

Comment: Yes it doesn't do much. but should one consider the future use cases may be more complex logic on forming the error string?

Comment: I mentioned UI code because size of code, limited memory, limited cpu etc when executing in a browser compared to server.